# mongodb Querying for a Date Range when date is saved as string

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm saving data into the bongo as bulk insert. The data that's an array of JSON object contain date, numeric, alphanumeric data all saved as string.

*Sample Data*

```
[{
    "CARDNO": "661",
    "HOLDERNO": "661",
    "HOLDERNAME": "S",
    "IODATE": "4/1/2012",
    "IOTIME": "00:03:27",
    "IOGATENO": "01-3",
    "IOGATENAME": "FWork",
    "IOSTATUS": "Entry",
    "DEPARTMENTNO": "1",
    "UPDATE_STATUS": "1"
}, {
    "CARDNO": "711",
    "HOLDERNO": "711",
    "HOLDERNAME": "P",
    "IODATE": "4/1/2012",
    "IOTIME": "04:35:33",
    "IOGATENO": "01-7",
    "IOGATENAME": "FDWork",
    "IOSTATUS": "Exit",
    "DEPARTMENTNO": "3",
    "UPDATE_STATUS": "1"
}]
```

*My Query*

var start = new Date(2012, 4, 15);
var end = new Date(2012, 4, 1);

```
collection.find({
    "IODATE": {
        $gte: start,
        $lt: end
    }
}).toArray(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data.length)
    }
    //res.send(data.length);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

It's not returning result, I think it is because the value of `"IODATE"` is in string inside db.

How to work around this issue? I may need to do bulk insert since the data can be of 200 million or so.

Comment: I would personally redo your schema, this is a complete flaw in your schema especially if you need to do more advanced things with the dates

Comment: @Sammaye I agree with you. but in my case its not a good option to change schema; even to say its impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One last try at this, because you don't have a good record of accepting good advice.

Your date formats as they stand are **going** to bite you. Even where trying to work around them. Here are the problems:

- The format is not **lexical**. Which means that even with a **string** comparison operators like [$gte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/), [$lte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) are just not going to work. A **lexical** date would be "2012-01-04" in "yyyy-mm-dd" format. That would work with the operators.
- You could look at [$substr](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) (and it's complete **lack** of documentation, search on SO for real usage) within [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) but your date format is lacking the double digit form of `day` and `month` ie "04/01/2012", so that is going to blow up the positional nature of the operator. Also you would **have** to transform before any [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) which means you **blow up** any chance of reducing your **pipeline input**, so you are stuck with **not** being able to filter your *large resultset* by `date`.

It's a horrible case, but there really is no other practical solution to the large data problem here than to **convert** your dates. Strings in the form that you have just do not cut it. Either, in order of preference convert to:

- BSON date
- epoch timestamp as long (whatever)
- Lexical string representation (as described)

Your main case seems to be filtering, so updating the dataset is the only pratical alternative. Otherwise you are stuck with "paging" results and doing a **lot** of manual work, that could otherwise be done server side.

Comment: K :). I will try to do something to convert my dates.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Sorry, I know it's a tough pill to swallow. But if you want to query you'd be in a lot of trouble without it. Beats iterating.

Comment: True :) Thing that bothers me is the bulk amount of data. It will take time if I'm gonna iterate through each and every record and convert it into date. Same goes with my numeric also.

Comment: @SreekeshOkky It's also true that just because an answer didn't provide a "golden rainbow" that solved all your problems, that it wasn't valid and informative, and gave you a direction to **move on**. The common practice when you receive an answer that **gave** you such direction is to accept it. Hence how I opened the starting phrase in my response. Someone just gave you knowledge. Be a fair citizen and repay the favour with an **accept** (and probably, fairly and up-vote). Your own rep came from where?